# mvn site:deploy reports failure but actually succeeds with nexus version 3.0.0-03

Tags: maven, nexus

Using the maven site plugin with the command:

```
mvn clean install deploy site site:deploy
```

gives a sequence of error messages when trying to deploy each of the site files:

```
Transfer finished. 3824 bytes copied in 0.015 seconds
Transfer error: java.io.IOException: Unable to create collection: https://repo.icatproject.org/repository/; status code = 400
Uploading: .//apidocs/allclasses-frame.html to https://repo.icatproject.org/repository/maven-sites/a/a1/1.0.1-SNAPSHOT/

#https://repo.icatproject.org/repository/maven-sites/a/a1/1.0.1-SNAPSHOT/./apidocs/allclasses-frame.html - Status code: 201

Transfer finished. 924 bytes copied in 0.015 seconds
Transfer error: java.io.IOException: Unable to create collection: https://repo.icatproject.org/repository/; status code = 400
Uploading: .//apidocs/script.js to https://repo.icatproject.org/repository/maven-sites/a/a1/1.0.1-SNAPSHOT/

#https://repo.icatproject.org/repository/maven-sites/a/a1/1.0.1-SNAPSHOT/./apidocs/script.js - Status code: 400
Transfer error: org.apache.maven.wagon.TransferFailedException: Failed to transfer file: https://repo.icatproject.org/repository/maven-sites/a/a1/1.0.1-SNAPSHOT/./apidocs/script.js. Return code is: 400
https://repo.icatproject.org/repository/maven-sites/a/a1/1.0.1- SNAPSHOT/ - Session: Disconnecting  
https://repo.icatproject.org/repository/maven-sites/a/a1/1.0.1-SNAPSHOT/ - Session: Disconnected
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 9.155 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-05-11T11:04:11+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 34M/408M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.4:deploy (default-cli) on project a.a1: Error uploading site: Failed to transfer file: https://repo.icatproject.org/repository/maven-sites/a/a1/1.0.1-SNAPSHOT/./apidocs/script.js. Return code is: 400 ->  [Help 1]
```

The error messages are shown in the example in the sonatype v3 documentation.  The output is identical in structure to http://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/3.0/reference/raw.html#_publishing_a_maven_site with a series of 400 error codes but they get [INFO] BUILD SUCCESS where I get BUILD FAILURE.

Comment: simply use `mvn clean deploy site site-deploy` if you use `install deploy` you duplicate many parts....

Comment: However this does not affect the underlying issue with site:deploy

Comment: If you are using Nexus as repository manager ? Which version of Nexus do you use? How does your distributionManagement look like?

Comment: distributionManagement --> ID of the URL in your pom must match the ID of a server in your settings.xml.  make sure you have enough privileges.

Comment: As in the question it is version 3.0.0-03. I must have sufficient privileges to be able to write at all. The output is identical in structure to http://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/3.0/reference/raw.html#_publishing_a_maven_site

Comment: I find that adding -Dwagon.webdav.continueOnFailure=true to the mvn command circumvents the problem however this is not a clean solution as it needs to be in the pom.

Comment: Still happening in Nexus 3.2 - https://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/3.2/reference/raw.html

Comment: Is there anything in the nexus.log file that might shed light on what's happening there?

Answer (score 0):

> Transfer error: org.apache.maven.wagon.TransferFailedException: Failed
>   to transfer file:
>   https://repo.icatproject.org/repository/maven-sites/a/a1/1.0.1-SNAPSHOT/./apidocs/script.js.
>   Return code is: 400

The output in our book and your deployment is slightly different.

The 400 response that failed the build in your output is from a file deployment, where the book only has it for directory path MKCOL requests.

One reason a 400 response for a file deployment ( not directory ) may happen is that file is already present inside the repository and the repository Deployment Policy prevents overwriting existing files.

Go to the maven-sites repository configuration in Nexus. Make sure the "Deployment  Policy" is set to "Allow Redeploy" - then try the deployment again.

If it still doesn't work, there should be more information in nexus.log on the server.